# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment termination failing due to non-existent RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I created an Elastic Beanstalk via the wizard and it made an an Amazon RDS database that I didn't use because we have our DB instances in a different RDS outside of Elastic Beanstalk.

I deleted the RDS instance which made the environment unstable and we couldn't use it anymore. However, we made a new environment and everything worked out.

Now, I am trying to terminate this other Beanstalk which we can't/won't use but it keeps failing the termination. As far as I could figure, it seems like when the RDS was created, the retention was set at 'take a snapshot', now that the RDS doesn't exist, it can't take a snapshot and fails terminating the environment.

All I need to do is get rid of this environment because it is just sitting there. How do I go about solving this problem?

For reference this is what the error logs look like:

```
2018-06-05 14:00:41 UTC-0500    ERROR   Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
2018-06-05 14:00:41 UTC-0500    ERROR   Deleting RDS database named: aa1ipjn4c8bwak9 failed Reason: DBInstance aa1ipjn4c8bwak9 not found. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: DBInstanceNotFound; Request ID: f8f17442-bd41-4188-9c7e-9408a5398a92)
2018-06-05 14:00:24 UTC-0500    INFO    rebuildEnvironment is starting.
2018-06-01 14:21:01 UTC-0500    ERROR   Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
2018-06-01 14:21:01 UTC-0500    ERROR   Deleting RDS database named: aa1ipjn4c8bwak9 failed Reason: DBInstance aa1ipjn4c8bwak9 not found. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: DBInstanceNotFound; Request ID: 0dba0c59-473f-4814-a6dd-2af7847be6c0)
```

Comment: if you still have your .war file deployed to that Elastic Beanstalk, try remove it first, refresh the page, and try deleting again

Comment: I tried to delete the version that was deployed to the said EBS but it gave me the same two Errors that are mentioned in the question. Is there any other way removing the deployed code from the EBS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be able to create a new RDS instance named `aa1ipjn4c8bwak9` and then delete the environment. I had to do something similar when I switched from the default ELB to an ALB.

I wish that EB didn't default to creating a database with the environment - in any sort of production environment, it's almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: That is such a dirty workaround, sadly that's the only thing that worked. Can't believe there is no provision for this. thanks :)

Comment: No problem. EB was a really promising technology, in my opinion, but it's getting left behind by other AWS offerings these days and is really showing its age.

Comment: Are there offerings that completely replace EB? if yes, I'd like to know and maybe migrate to them already because EB is definitely not making things very easy.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "replace". In my opinion, ElasticBeanstalk was designed to manage the lifecycle of traditional three-tier web applications. It automates infrastructure provisioning, application deployment, capacity scaling, and monitoring. If your application fits the EB paradigm, it can still be a good choice. The challenges come when you want to do something outside its framework. If you want more flexibility, you might want to look at CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, or CodeStar, or if your needs are simpler, Lightsail or Lambda might be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that does give me a better insight

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the AWS CloudFormation console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Stacks.
3. In the Stack name column, select the stack for the Elastic Beanstalk environment that you want to delete.

Note: In the Status column for your stack, you should see DELETE_FAILED.

Tip: You can identify your stack by verifying that the environment ID from the Description column in the AWS CloudFormation console matches the environment ID of your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

4. Choose Delete.
5. In the pop-up window, select the AWSEBRDSDatabase check box in the Resources to retain - optional section, and then choose Delete Stack.

Source:- [AWS Knowledge Centre](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-deleted-rds-database/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding our experience in case it helps.

The normal terminate environment failed due to failing to terminate the RDS instance due to being maxed out on RDS snapshots. (In theory, one could go and up that limit as a workaround...). We manually terminated the RDS instance. We still could not terminate the environment. Inspecting the CloudFormation console (Resources tab), we see an AWSEBSecurityGroup and a AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup both with status DELETE_FAILED. In some cases, there are 2 lb security groups listed in the Security Groups console for the environment (if the operation involves swapping LBs and failure happens before the old one is torn down). The key is *ONE* of them has a dependency on an orphaned RDS security group (group name prefix = 'rds-awseb'). Interactively, there seems no choice but to try deleting both. You are offered a link to see the dependencies - for one of them the dependency will be the rds security group. Click through to the Security Groups console and delete it. Once that's gone, we are able to either delete the stack from the CloudFormation console (which leaves a zombie EB environment behind) OR (better) terminate the EB environment from the EB console or using the CLI. Depending on the sequence, have found that EB terminate still fails due to the failure to terminate the now-missing RDS instance. In this case, deleting the stack from the CF console works (click 'retain' when prompted) - *THEN* the EB terminate succeeds. Be sure to do that EB terminate because there are usually yet other resources not deleted when the CF stack deletion has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem with regard to a security group. I was able to delete the environment by rebuilding the environment.

Steps:

1. Rebuild Environment

Under the Actions drop down in the top right corner of the elastic beanstalk, click on the **Rebuild Environment** option

Note: This might take some time to complete

2. Terminate Environment

Under the same Actions drop down click on **Terminate Environment**

P.S: 
[Screenshot of Actions drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NTBE.png)

Comment: I tried that and it failed for me, I think while rebuilding the environment it deletes all its configuration first, and while doing so, in my case, the rebuild is also erroring out on deleting the database (which in this case doesn't exist). So my rebuild has failed too. Is there no way of getting out of this mess. It feels very constricting in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I first deleted RDS that was being used by one of my EBS env.
Then I deleted Cloudformation tasks.
Then deleted EBS Applications and that automatically deleted the EBS env.